# webpack, restrict what can be imported

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, webpack, import

Is there a way in webpack to restrict what files can be imported?

Say I want to be able to import files that are in the same directory, as well as the parent directory, but nothing above that parent directory?  For example:

These work

```
import { blah } from "./script.js";

import { blah2 } from "./../gui/textbox.js";

import { blah3 } from  "./../I/can/go/as/deep/down/as/I/want/here.js";
```

But this wouldn't work

```
import { passwords } from "./../../passwords.txt";
```

Because that would go up two (or x number of) directories, instead of just one.

Comment: Didn't you try this plugin? https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/

Comment: @Harshana I didn't see that, no.  Thanks for the reference, I'll look into it more

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:security]. What are the security stakes here? What specific attack are you trying to prevent?

Comment: @Louis I'm making an app that downloads remote code as "plugins", then webpacks them and serves them with an electron browser.  Among other security precautions (https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security), I have to ensure that these plugins only have access to their own directory, the API I expose, and nothing more.

Comment: @Isaac Are you preventing the plugins from creating filesystem links? If not, then it would be possible for a bad actor to overcome the mechanism described in the answer you accepted.

Comment: @Louis That's a good point that I didn't think about, nice catch.  By filesystem links, are you referring to something like this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), or more along the lines of "file:///folder/file.txt"

Comment: I'm thinking filesystem symbolic links *and* hard links. Actually, you could write the loader to detect symbolic links and resolve them. However, Unix-based filesystems allow multiple hard links to the same inode. (And there seem to be an equivalent for Windows-based filesystems.) There's no portable and reasonable way to detect this case. Whether it is a problem depends on how your plugins are packed. As `npm` packages, they could create in `postinstall` hard links to whatever they want and your Webpack loader wouldn't know. You'd need something else to prevent them from breaking out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a loader to restrict webpack imports to specific files.

```
// file: webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: path.resolve('my-webpack-loader.js'),
            options: {/* ... */}
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Then throw if the resource file is outside `./src` and `./node_modules` directory or any directory of your choice.

```
// file: my-webpack-loader.js
const { getOptions } = require('loader-utils');
const validateOptions = require('schema-utils');
const path = require('path');

const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    test: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
};

function handler(source) {
  const options = getOptions(this);

  if(this.resourcePath.indexOf(path.resolve('./node_modules')) !== 0) {
    if(this.resourcePath.indexOf(path.resolve('./src')) !== 0) {
      throw `Reseource loading restricted for ${this.resourcePath}`;
    }
  }

  validateOptions(schema, options, 'My Webpack Loader');

  return source;
}

module.exports = handler;
```

For more info see [writing a webpack loader](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/).

Comment: Couldn't you get around this by setting your resource path to something like "./src/../../../passwords.txt"?  However something like this may work `if(resolvedRequestedFilePath.indexOf(allowedFilePath) !== 0){throw new Error("restricted")});` where `allowedFilePath` would be the path to the allowed directory, and `resolvedRequestedFilePath` would be `path.resolve(this.resourcePath)`

Comment: No, the `resourcePath` is always the absolute path of the file. It resolves `./src/../abc` to `./abc`.

Answer (score 3):

`react-dev-utils` has a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dev-utils#new-modulescopepluginappsrc-string--string-allowedfiles-string) for this.

> This Webpack plugin ensures that relative imports from app's source
>   directories don't reach outside of it.

```
var path = require('path');
var ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    // ...
    plugins: [
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
      // ...
    ],
    // ...
  },
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I'm not using React with my website, will that be a problem?

Comment: I don't think so. This plugin doesn't seem to depend on anything related to react. The code is pretty short, you can check it yourself: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin.js